# Using Decorator pattern with abstract class

Tags: c#, .net

Can I decorate abstract class Player by changing output of property Name. For example my class is :

```
public abstract class Player
{
    private FootBall ball;

    private string name;

    public Player(FootBall ball, string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.ball = ball;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
    }


    public virtual void Update()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Player {0} says that ball is at position {1} {2} {3}", this.Name, this.ball.Position.PositionX, this.ball.Position.PositionY, this.ball.Position.PositionZ));
    }

}
```

I have two classes GamePlayer and Referee both inheriting Player:

```
 GamePlayer : Player { // implementation }
 Referee: Player { // implementation }
```

I want to decorate property Name with for example two Decorations :
SoccerPlayer and BasketBallPlayer. The property Name should return for example

```
John - basketballPlayer
John - soccerPlayer:
John - basketballPlayer - soccerPlayer
```

Comment: I don't get the example. If you have GamePlayer and Referee, what should be the value of Name property for these 2 classes?

Comment: For example I create :
Player  player = new GamePlayer(new FootBall(),"John"); 
And I want to decorate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decorator pattern works best with interfaces.  If you wanted to use it with an abstract base class, you would need to make any methods you want to decorate `virtual` so that derived classes can override them to do their own processing before delegating to the decorated base types `base.MyMethod` method.

At this point you are basically using inheritance though.  The only distinction between a decorated base class and inheritance is that in the decorator pattern, your derived class would have the `Is A` and `Has A` relationship to the base class, whereas inheritance would only have the `Is A` relationship.  It would probably be indistinguishable from outside your derived class, so might as well just inherit.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx

Comment: So would it be a bad design decision if I create separate interface IPlayerDecorator and move the Name property in it. And then I inherit both the abstract class and the interface:

       `Referee : Player, IPlayerDecorator { //implementation }`

Comment: No, that would be the preferred way to use Decorator.  Everywhere you want to be able to use decorated objects, just pass around `IMyDecoratableInterface`.  Then consuming code doesn't have to know anything about the concrete implementation.

Comment: @Grizabela as JamesFaix mentioned, that would be the preferable design. Although I would highly recommend to _not_ use Decorator in the interface name. Just name it `IPlayer`. No one needs to know that the interface _might_ be implemented by a decorator. All they need to know that something is a `IPlayer` and thus has a `Name` property.

Comment: I'm 100% with Patrick on that one.  I just use silly names like `IAmAnInterface` to make the usage of fake type names clear when demonstrating techniques.  The Decorator pattern should generally be a "sneaky" pattern in the sense that client code should not have to know that it is being used at all.  Conversely, it is usually appropriate to name a class that initializes `Blob` instances `BlobFactory` because client code should usually be aware that `BlobFactory` is creating `Blob`s.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations JamesFaix and Patrick Huizinga